# Javascript: if text input has any value

Tags: javascript

The snippet of code below does "something" if a particular checkbox in a form is checked and a particular text input is empty.

```
else if (myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value=="")
```

How can I modify it so that it does something if the checkbox is checked and the text input has ANY value (the user inserted something in it).

Thank you, sorry if this is a very basic question..

Comment: `!myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value!=""` ??

Comment: grab some book on basic javascript programming, read "conditions" chapter, and play with the `!=` operator.

Comment: cant you do it by just changing `myform.mytextinput.value==""` to `myform.mytextinput.value!=""`

Comment: basic question you say? free rep. everyone get in here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need <> or in this case !=

```
else if (myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value!="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
else if (myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value)
```

That expression would evaluate to true if the checkbox is checked and there is something in the input field.

When you do a boolean evaluation on the content of a given variable it will evaluate to `false` if the content is any of the following: `false`, `""`(empty string), `0`, `null` or `undefined`. Anything else will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value!=="")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this would work:

`else if (myform.mycheckbox[1].checked && myform.mytextinput.value.length > 0)`

That would work as long as there was at least 1 character in the input.